# How do I make this jq expression, which works in jq >= 1.5, backwards-compatible / correct for versions < 1.5

Tags: json, bash, foreach, jq

In any version (that i've tried) of `jq >= 1.5`, **this works fine**.  
In any version of `jq <= 1.4`, I get the following error:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected as, expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START
```

There's a lot of information around on the error: *"expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START"*, so far what I've seen has not applied here, I wonder if it's the **`as`** that I am not implementing reliably

**I can recreate the problem with this trivial code:** (can be copied/pasted as is to test)

```
jq \
'(..|.liveBroadcastContent?'\
'| foreach . as $item (.; if $item == null then false else . end)) as $chanstatus '\
'| {location:"location",
channel:"channelid",
current_id:"vId",
id_status:$chanstatus,
url:"https://youtu.be/\("vId")"}' \
<<<'{"liveBroadcastContent":true}'
```

**Desired result achieved on `jq > 1.5`**:

```
{
  "location": "location",
  "channel": "channelid",
  "current_id": "vId",
  "id_status": true,
  "url": "https://youtu.be/vId"
}
```

**What it's supposed to do:**

- If `liveBroadcastContent` **exists** in the input: then output it's value in the `id_status` key
- If `liveBroadcastContent` **does not exist**: then output `false` in the `id_status` key
- Output everything else as written

**Actual Input**:

[This](https://ybin.me/p/e72323d0610e321c#8azNQERYjSV1uBgXiSnLSLIv3dQuex3+8NbBj10WQR0=) is what goes into the program when there **is** a live stream present.
[This](https://ybin.me/p/94bf4e6669950f1b#mkLPmDJ+1h0pcGAPKGr1nAliCxHbVyAks9h3uYQrJWY=) is what goes into the program when there **is no** live streams

Hence I thought `..|.liveBroadcastContent?` was the most reliable way to basically say "*If this key appears **somewhere** in the data, please return it's value in **<this>** part of my fixed-format output data*"

Now that the application is obvious, please note that I am aware of using other methods such as checking the value of `"totalResults"`, in combination with `HTTP 200`, amongst others, however:

1. This application of `jq` may be useful elsewhere and I'd like to address it as it.
2. This whole program is a shared program invoked as a one-shot on demand basis, which is a backup method (API key) of a more comprehensively implemented oauth server application.  On occasion the input data is different, thus I just want to recursively search for `liveBroadcastContent`

**EDIT:** Just to clarify - this **isn't** about the behavior of `jq` across versions (something that would belong in the `jq` forums) - It's about making the most robust portable code.  I tend to think that versions >1.5 are simply forgiving a poorly formed expression (which I'm trying to work out here)

Comment: You don't need the backslashes; a single, multiline string is fine as the filter argument to `jq`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the edits.  If I do try this, [this](https://ybin.me/p/13a75e0da1ecd11d#ErHv9BawdPWLgrwXuWq881VXCeDzofPcHfTbcgY/3GA=) is what happens (TLDR: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 8:`)

Comment: I think that was due to the formerly doubled backslash you had, not any whitespace in the filter. I can reproduce that error with `"\\("foo")"` vs `"\("foo")"`

Comment: It would be far more helpful for us to see what your input looks like rather than giving us this very simplified example. Give us something more representative of what you're using.

Comment: @JeffMercado - Retrospectively I regret not including this.  I was trying to be careful not to overbloat the question with irrelevance as I mistakenly thought I could reproduce it trivially.  I tried hard to follow the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - unfortunately I didn't include enough information.  I've now edited.  I wonder if I should now edit the question also for the benefit of the community and searchers.  to "Reliable way with jq to search recursively for the presence of specific key and include it as part of a new object" ?  Would appreciate this guidance

Comment: I only ask because I feel the recursion (`..`) is probably unnecessary and the use of `foreach` an attempt at a solution that could be written more efficiently. Your example is using hardcoded output values when I feel that it might be more useful to show how you want your input to be mapped to your output, and in a way compatible with jq 1.4. Then we could provide some useful techniques you might not be familiar with but could use in the future.

Comment: @JeffMercado What you've said is basically why I posted the question - I've included the input as an edit to the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The reason your snippet fails in jq 1.4 is that `foreach` was only introduced in version 1.5.
2. I'm not sure that your program with `foreach` is consistent with your stated requirements, which unfortunately are slightly unclear. For example, what if the "liveBroadcastContent" key appears more than once in the input JSON entity?
3. Your stated requirements as I understand them (glossing over the ambiguity) would correspond to the following program, which has been tested with jq 1.4, 1.5 and the current "master" version:

```
 (reduce (..| select(type == "object" and has("liveBroadcastContent"))) as $item
    (false; $item | .liveBroadcastContent)) as $chanstatus
 | {location:"location",
    channel:"channelid",
    current_id:"vId",
    id_status:$chanstatus,
    url:"https://youtu.be/\("vId")"}
```

4. For multiline programs such as this, it's usually much more convenient to use the -f option of jq, e.g. `jq -f program.jq`
5. If you need to accommodate jq 1.3 as well, then you'd have to handle  `..`, which can be done by using `dotdot` defined as follows:

```
def dotdot:
  recurse(if (type | . == "object" or . == "array") then .[] else empty end);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The `INIT` in the `foreach` seems to have some significance.  You can see [here](https://ybin.me/p/6c3fe35b4935c7be#w+jOjcnuTkuuL/zfw1hChrb4OGI0cr50CIh2mZUzRVc=) the difference between the two programs you've provided and the original using `foreach`.  I initially omitted a real dataset in my question thinking it was bordering on irrelevant, but [here](https://ybin.me/p/e72323d0610e321c#8azNQERYjSV1uBgXiSnLSLIv3dQuex3+8NbBj10WQR0=) is what *actually* goes into the program.  I will post back when and if I work this out.

Comment: My apologies for the error. I've updated the response accordingly, but maybe I'm not understanding the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your input actually looks like, but given what you've shown here, it doesn't have to be that complicated.

```
{
    location: "location",
    channel: "channelid",
    current_id: "vId",
    id_status: (.liveBroadcastContent? // false),
    url: "https://youtu.be/vId"
}
```

You wanted to get the value of `liveBroadcastContent` if it exists, otherwise `false` and that's what precisely `.liveBroadcastContent? // false` does (assuming `null` is not a valid value).

---

Seeing your full input object, it seems like a search result from a web api. I don't think using recursion here is really necessary. If the goal is take each of the results and display various information about each one, I would write this filter instead. (guessing at some of the fields)

```
.items[] | {
    location: .channelTitle,
    channel: .channelId,
    current_id: .id,
    id_status: (.liveBroadcastContent? // false),
    url: "https://youtu.be/\(.id)"
}
```

If on the other hand, you were using the search results to determine whether a feed was available (based on your negative input case), I think it would be better to approach it finding the property on the list of results, rather than just the mere existence of the property anywhere.

I would do this instead:

```
{
    location: "location",
    channel: "channelid",
    current_id: "vId",
    id_status: ([.items[].snippet.liveBroadcastContent | select(. != null)][0] // false),
    url: "https://youtu.be/vId"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very useful application of `? // false` when null is not valid